# unable to print more than 20 records using mPDF (timeout/memory issue?)

Tags: php, mpdf

I'm trying to print a series of timecards (up to 150) to a pdf.  it works fine for one record but fails for more than 20.

Following is the code for a sample record

```
<div class='container'><h3>Timecard</h3><table style='table-layout: fixed;width:100%;text-align:left;'><tr><td class='infoItem' width='265px'><span class='fieldID'>Employee Name:</span>  Gomez Addams</td><td class='infoItem'><span class='fieldID'>EE#:</span>  9502</td></tr><tr><td class='infoItem'><span class='fieldID'>Dept:</span>  County Board</td><td colspan=2 align='left' class='infoItem'><h4><span class='fieldID'>JobID:</span> 13 <em class='fieldID grey'>(full-time non-exempt Sheriff Union contract with holiday)</em></h4></td></tr><tr><td class='infoItem'><span class='fieldID'>Payperiod:</span> 100 <em class='fieldID grey'>(Mar 10 to Mar 23 2012)</em></td><td class='infoItem'><span class='fieldID'>Pay Date:</span>  Mar 30 2012</td></tr></table><hr />
<table  class='timecard' width='658px'><tr><th class='timeHdr'>day</th><th class='timeHdr'>date</th><th class='timeHdr'>1000<br/>reg<br/>hrs</th><th class='timeHdr'>1004<br/>OT<br/>1x</th><th class='timeHdr'>1005<br/>OT<br/>1.5x</th><th class='timeHdr'>1035<br/>PTO<br/>used</th><th class='timeHdr'>1045<br/>comp<br/>used</th><th class='timeHdr'>1066<br/>comp<br/>1x</th><th class='timeHdr'>1067<br/>comp<br/>1.5x</th><th class='timeHdr'>other<br/>hrs</th><th class='timeHdr'>total<br/>hrs</th><th class='timeHdr'>1003<br/>hol<br/>prem</th><th class='timeHdr'>1007<br/>shift<br/>diff</th><th class='timeHdr'>1010<br/>out of<br/>class</th></tr>
<tr class='even'><td class='timeHdr'>sat</td><td align='center' class='timeHdr'>3/10</td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='rowTot'><div id='row0'></div></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td></tr>
<tr class='odd'><td class='timeHdr'>sun</td><td align='center' class='timeHdr'>3/11</td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='rowTot'><div id='row1'></div></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td></tr>
<tr class='even'><td class='timeHdr'>mon</td><td align='center' class='timeHdr'>3/12</td><td class='timeView'>8</td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='rowTot'><div id='row2'>8</div></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td></tr>
<tr class='odd'><td class='timeHdr'>tue</td><td align='center' class='timeHdr'>3/13</td><td class='timeView'>8</td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='rowTot'><div id='row3'>8</div></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td></tr>
<tr class='even'><td class='timeHdr'>wed</td><td align='center' class='timeHdr'>3/14</td><td class='timeView'>8</td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='rowTot'><div id='row4'>8</div></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td></tr>
<tr class='odd'><td class='timeHdr'>thu</td><td align='center' class='timeHdr'>3/15</td><td class='timeView'>8</td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='rowTot'><div id='row5'>8</div></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td></tr>
<tr class='even'><td class='timeHdr'>fri</td><td align='center' class='timeHdr'>3/16</td><td class='timeView'>8</td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='rowTot'><div id='row6'>8</div></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td></tr>
<tr class='odd'><td class='timeHdr'>sat</td><td align='center' class='timeHdr'>3/17</td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='rowTot'><div id='row7'></div></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td></tr>
<tr class='even'><td class='timeHdr'>sun</td><td align='center' class='timeHdr'>3/18</td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='rowTot'><div id='row8'></div></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td></tr>
<tr class='odd'><td class='timeHdr'>mon</td><td align='center' class='timeHdr'>3/19</td><td class='timeView'>8</td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='rowTot'><div id='row9'>8</div></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td></tr>
<tr class='even'><td class='timeHdr'>tue</td><td align='center' class='timeHdr'>3/20</td><td class='timeView'>4</td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'>4</td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='rowTot'><div id='row10'>8</div></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td></tr>
<tr class='odd'><td class='timeHdr'>wed</td><td align='center' class='timeHdr'>3/21</td><td class='timeView'>3.5</td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'>4.5</td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='rowTot'><div id='row11'>8</div></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td></tr>
<tr class='even'><td class='timeHdr'>thu</td><td align='center' class='timeHdr'>3/22</td><td class='timeView'>8</td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='rowTot'><div id='row12'>8</div></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td></tr>
<tr class='odd'><td class='timeHdr'>fri</td><td align='center' class='timeHdr'>3/23</td><td class='timeView'>8</td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='rowTot'><div id='row13'>8</div></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td><td class='timeView'></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan=2 style='background: #e6f4ff;' class='timeHdr'>totals</td><td align='center' class='colTot'><div id='col0'>71.5</div></td><td align='center' class='colTot'><div id='col1'></div></td><td align='center' class='colTot'><div id='col2'></div></td><td align='center' class='colTot'><div id='col3'>8.5</div></td><td align='center' class='colTot'><div id='col4'></div></td><td align='center' class='colTot'><div id='col5'></div></td><td align='center' class='colTot'><div id='col6'></div></td><td align='center' class='colTot'><div id='col7'></div></td><td align='center' class='totTot'>80</td><td align='center' class='colTot'><div id='col9'></div></td><td align='center' class='colTot'><div id='col10'></div></td><td align='center' class='colTot'><div id='col11'></div></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan=2 class='timeHdr' style='vertical-align: top;'>comments</td><td colspan=14 class='comment'> </td></tr>
</table><hr /><table style='table-layout: fixed;width:100%;text-align:left;'><td colspan=2 ><em class='grey'>This form is due in the Auditor/Treasurer's Office by 9:00am on Monday after the end of the pay period.  No overtime without authorization is allowed.&nbsp; I affirm that the information contained herein is true and correct to the best of my knowledge.</em></td></tr><tr><td colspan=2>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td class='infoItem' valign='top'><span class='fieldID'>Employee:</span>  Gomez Addams</td><td class='infoItem'><span class='fieldID'>Supervisor:</span>   </td></tr><tr><td class='infoItem'><span class='fieldID'>Employee Approved:</span>  </td><td class='infoItem'><span class='fieldID'>Supervisor Approved:</span>  </td></tr></table><br /></table>

<h4>Payroll Notes:</h4><p>note 4</p></div>
```

The line breaks are the same as what is being printed I gather that matters...

so based on that, I then have this:

```
ini_set("memory_limit", "256M"); 
$stylesheet = file_get_contents('../css/timecardPDF.css');
$mpdf=new mPDF();
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);
<loop>$html=above code;$mpdf->WriteHTML($html,2);</end loop> 
$mpdf->Output('../timecards/file.pdf','F');
exit;
```

so everything is exactly as it should be until I try to loop more than 20 times.  What can I do to get the kit and kaboodle (150 records) to print to a pdf doc?

Thank you for your kind consideration!

Comment: for anyone who happens on a similar issue:   turns out it was just timing out so extended the php timeout (set_time_limit(#ms)) and it works (just takes a looong time!)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

for anyone who happens on a similar issue: turns out it was just timing out so extended the php timeout (set_time_limit(#ms)) and it works (just takes a looong time!)

Comment: This is not a solution, just very bad practise. Depending on your server environment, this will potentially cause your apache2 process to max out its memory and cause all other page requests to be extremely slow until your script has finished.

Comment: probably fair to call it a work-around rather than a solution.

Comment: Fair enough. But to be honest, I think Mpdfs Output method has some bad code innit causing it to be slow. It actually gets exponentially slower. We are considering using a different library.

Comment: I went with Mpdf because I'm using it with lots of tables and they handle that better than some.  I'd be interested to hear what you find - I looked for a while but needed a solution more than I needed the best solution.

Comment: I will post a solution here once I find the best solution. We are trying to avoid using tables because we need very precise styling and it works better with divs.